# Python encoding/decoding error

Tags: python, unicode

I'm using Python 2.7.3. My operating system is Windows7(32-bit).
In the cmd, I typed this code:

```
chcp 1254
```

and I converted decoding system to 1254.
But,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:cp1254 -*-
print "öçışğüÖÇİŞĞÜ"
```

When I ran above codes, I got that output:

```
÷²■­³ÍÃ¦Ìº▄
```

But when I put u after the print command (print u"öçışğüÖÇİŞĞÜ")

When I edited codes as that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:cp1254 -*-

import os
a = r"C:\\"
b = "ö"
print os.path.join(a, b)
```

I got that output:

```
÷
```

That's why when I tried

```
print unicode(os.path.join(a, b))
```

command. I got that error:

```
print unicode(os.path.join(a, b))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 13: ordinal
 not in range(128)
```

By trying a different way:

```
print os.path.join(a, b).decode("utf-8").encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
```

When I tried above code, I got that error:

```
print os.path.join(a, b).decode("utf-8").encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 13: invalid start byte
```

As a result, I can't get rid of this error. How can I solve it ?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not reproducing the error: the initial code works fine here.

Comment: What is the output of this command ?: chcp

Comment: "C:\\ö"

I tried it on 2 Python 2.7 installs, one a Windows 7 32 bit install.

Comment: Are you running this from the standard "Command Prompt"?

Comment: For me, it produces the incorrect encoding C:\\├╢ with the standard command prompt, from Cygwin, it works perfectly fine, suggesting the issue is the representation of the encoding in stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your original code, but use `chcp 857` (the Turkish OEM code page) I can reproduce your issue, so I do not think you were running `chcp 1254`:

```
÷²■­³ÍÃ¦Ìº▄
```

If you declare your source encoding as:

```
# -*- coding:cp1254 -*-
```

You must save your source code in that encoding.  If you don't use Unicode strings, you must also use the same encoding at the console.  Then it works correctly.

Example (source declared `cp1254`, but saved incorrectly as `cp1252`, and console `chcp 1254`):

```
öçisgüÖÇISGÜ
```

Example (source declared and saved correctly as `cp1254`, console `chcp 1254`):

```
öçışğüÖÇİŞĞÜ
```

It is important to note that with Unicode strings, you don't have to match the source encoding with the encoding of your console.

Example (declared and saved as UTF-8, with Unicode string):

```
#!python2
# -*- coding:utf8 -*-
print u"öçışğüÖÇİŞĞÜ"
```

Output (use any code page that supports Turkish...1254, 857, 1026...):

```
öçışğüÖÇİŞĞÜ
```